# Plot with title which depends of variables

Tags: python, plot, title

(Sorry for my english...)

I'm looking for a method to creat a plot.title which depends of my variables already defined at the begining.

I'm not asking you to make it for me. Just to help me to find documents, sites, forum or things like that. I haven't find in on Google and i don't know what to type coz english isn't my native language.

Currently, i'm showing a graph and creating a pdf. which also contain the graph, like that :

```
graphic = plt.figure(1)
plt.plot(ts, xs, label="Position")
plt.plot(ts, vs, label="Velocity")
plt.title("euler-k-10-c-0.1-dt-0.01")
plt.legend()
plt.xlabel("Time ts")
plt.ylabel("Valors of position xs and velocity vs")
plt.show()
pp = PdfPages("Graphics.pdf")
pp.savefig(graphic, dpi = 300, transparent = True)
pp.close()
```

What i want to, is to modify this line :
    plt.title("euler-k-10-c-0.1-dt-0.01")

I'm supposed to enter the valors of k, c and dt variables, and i want to change the name of the graphic to make it concur with the valors choosen for these variables.

For example, my code ask to enter the valors of k, c and dt, so i enter :
k = 1 ; c = 0 ; dt = 0.1

Then the graph title is : euler-k-1-c-0-dt-0.1

Thank you very much !

Comment: you can do something like `plt.title("euler-k-{:f}-c-{:f}-dt-{:f}".format(k, c, dt))`. `f` means float, you can control decimal points like `{:0.01f}` to print two significant figures

Answer (score 0):

The string entering the plot title can be composed of variables like any other string. In your particular case, something like

```
k = 1
c = 0
dt = 0.1
plt.title(f'euler-k-{k}-c-{c}-dt-{dt}')
```

would do the job.

Here we've used formatted string literals; for other approaches to formatting a string, see [e.g. this overview](https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/).

Answer (score 0):

```
def make_plots(tx,xs,k,c,dt)
    graphic = plt.figure(1)
    plt.plot(ts, xs, label="Position")
    plt.plot(ts, vs, label="Velocity")
    plt.title(f'euler-k-{k}-c-{c}-dt-{dt}')
    plt.legend()
    plt.xlabel("Time ts")
    plt.ylabel("Valors of position xs and velocity vs")
    plt.show()
    pp = PdfPages("Graphics.pdf")
    pp.savefig(graphic, dpi = 300, transparent = True)
    pp.close()
```

Make a function and call it as often as you change your k,c and dt.

Answer (score 0):

Ow ! Thank you, i didn't think i was that easy.

> Make a function and call it as often as you change your k,c and dt.

Hum.. Yes thank you ! But that's not the point haha.

this :
 plt.title(f'euler-k-{k}-c-{c}-dt-{dt}')
answer my question. It works ! Now i can do that :

k = int(input("Enter the valor of k : "))

And the valor of k that i entered is considered in the title of my graph !

Thanks !

PS : I was also wondering why there was an error message when i wrote it :

k = input("Enter the valor of k : ")

It's because the "thing" you write when the input is executed, is considered as a string, and not an integer or a float ! So i have to add int() to make it works !

Thank you guys, you're awesome !